# Questions on WordPress Codex Concept

Tags: custom-post-types, codex

When I was reading the WordPress Codex about outputting the Post and Pages I saw these two Titles at [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types)

> Output a list of all **registered** post types

and

> Output a list of all **public** custom post types

now can you please let me know 
1 - What are Registered posts? Is there any un-registered one?
2 - What are the Public Custom Post Types? is there any Private one?

Thanks

Comment: `register_post_type` have a parameter `public`. Controls how the type is visible to authors and readers. If a post type public is true then it is `exclude_from_search`, `publicly_queryable`, `show_in_nav_menus`, and `show_ui`. read more here. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: Also all post types must be registered (there is no un-registered post type) but a post type can have option to be public or not.

Comment: @Roberthue - please add that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding here.

`register_post_type` function have a parameter `public` which controls how the type is visible to authors and readers.

If public parameter of a post type is **true** then post type will be `exclude_from_search`, `publicly_queryable`, `show_in_nav_menus`, and `show_ui`. [Read more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) about it in [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) function.

Also all post types must be registered to use in WordPress. So there is not such thing as `un-registered post type` but a registered post type can have option to be public or not based on what value you supply.